# How can I evaluate: $\int^{\frac{\pi}{4}}_0\frac{\tan{x^2}}{x^2}dx$ and $\int^{\frac{\pi}{4}}_0\frac{\tan{x^2}}{\sqrt{x}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

So using the Inside Interesting Integrals book, I learned how to handle $\int^\infty_0\frac{\sin{x^2}}{x^2}dx$ & $\int^\infty_0\frac{\cos{x^2}}{x^2}dx$ (the latter doesn't converge naturally), and $\int^\infty_0\frac{\cos{x^2}}{\sqrt{x}}dx$ & $\int^\infty_0\frac{\sin{x^2}}{\sqrt{x}}dx$

But don't know how to evaluate $$\int^{\frac{\pi}{4}}_0\frac{\tan{x^2}}{x^2}dx$$ and $$\int^{\frac{\pi}{4}}_0\frac{\tan{x^2}}{\sqrt{x}}dx$$

Any techniques to tackle these integrals?

Comment: It doesn't seem that you can do anything about them, except for numerical evaluation.

Comment: I agree with Momo: Mathematica suggests no closed form for either of them, and WolframAlpha doesn't recognise decimal approximations of them.

Comment: hopeless...with some luck you can find a hypergeometric rep. here but nothing more

Comment: I'm not even able to find a Hyp.Rep. 

I'm just browsing through G&R

Comment: The upper limit seems random